# Date Selector not showing up in Rules

Tags: views, rules, entities

I have created an Entity Reference view, that provides a list of users. This is used as a field in a content type so that someone creating the content type, can check off one or more users from the list.

I then have a rule with a "Content is of type" condition. In my Action I add a variable that is a "list of user items" and using the Data Selector, I was able to choose "[node:field-people]" which I could loop through and get the selected users and then proceed to email them.

The rule worked great. Then I tried to recreate it in my test system. And for the life of me, I cannot get the [node:field-people] to show up as a Data Selector anymore. I also tried going back to my Dev system, and if I create another field using the same Entity Reference view, and naming the field peopletest, identical to the original field, "[node:field-peopletest]" doesn't show up either! So, I can't recreate the rule in either Dev or Test, even though I have created it once already in Dev.

Is there any chance I disabled or removed a module that had created "[node:field-people]" for me? Or does someone know which module is supposed to create that node:field-people for me so I can see if there's configuration that has been changed or maybe I've run into a bug in that module?

Answer (score 0):

Rules works in an interesting way and only shows you fields in the actions based on selections you have already made in the 'Conditions' sections.

Frequently, including a '**Content is of type**' condition or a '**Entity has field**' condition, will trigger it to include related fields in the 'Action' sections.

So double-check the newly created rules.  If you're not making sure your node is of a certain type or contains specific fields, the Actions section will only include generic fields for you.

Let us know if that works in your case...